# how to overide simplenews for drupal tpl and subscribe without being registered

Tags: email, drupal, newsletter, subscribe, drupal-blocks

How do I make a simple block to subscribe myself by providing my email in simlenews, without having to register myself.
i'm using drupal 6

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable subscribe to newsletters in "simplenews module"
go to permission -->simplenews module -->subscribe to newsletters [enable for anonymous user]

save and clear cache

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable the permission subscribe to issues to the anonymous users to allow non registered user to subscribe to your mailing list.